# How to add CASE in the SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server

I need the output from this.. i know this is wrong it is just an example

```
SELECT 
     customer_name,
     ((Qty * 0.5), *
     (CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(month, Appointment_Date,getdate())) < 12 )'Incentive' 
FROM t1,t2 
WHERE t1.customer_code = t2.customer_code
```

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve.. Making us to guess from your totally wrong code is waste of time  for both you and me

Comment: bro i need the ouput of the people with  datediff month less than 12 so i need to use case here

Comment: Why not a `where` clause ? `..Where datediff (month, Appointment_Date,getdate()) < 12`

Comment: where i need to use 
(QTY * 0.5) * Where datediff (month, Appointment_Date,getdate()) < 12
If i use like this it will not calculate

Comment: Still not clear. Post sample data and expected result

Comment: And your `CASE` expression in wrong..

Comment: This is my actual query
select  customer_name,(Qty * 0.5)* (datediff (month, Appointment_Date,getdate())) 'Incentive' 
from t1,t2 
where  t1.customer_code = t2.customer_code
customer                Incentive
Anand                17.5
Amar                 21.0
Ajesh                28.0
Ashok                28.0

here the datediff will give the difference of appointdate and presentdate for example 7,9,13
I need to only values less than 12 for datediff and it should be multilplied with (qty * 0.5) * (datediff value which is less than 12)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
select  customer_name,((Qty * 0.5) *
(case when (datediff (month, Appointment_Date,getdate()) < 12 ) then
datediff (month, Appointment_Date,getdate()) else 1 end ) )'Incentive' 
from t1,t2 
where  t1.customer_code = t2.customer_code
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your comments (please read introductory notes on how to post on S.O.), maybe you can use a query like this.

I changed your original query using JOIN clause too.

```
SELECT 
     customer_name,
     Qty * 0.5 *DATEDIFF(month, Appointment_Date,getdate()) AS INCENTIVE
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.customer_code = t2.customer_code
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, Appointment_Date,getdate()) < 12
```